# Hyper-V books/resources

Tags: hyper-v

I'm looking to develop solutions on the Hyper-V (like L2/L3 monitoring and intrusion detection etc). Are there any resources that I can read to understand the internals of Hyper-V and the APIs it exposes and how to interact with them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[A quick google search reveals plenty of resources:](https://www.google.com/#sclient=psy-ab&q=msdn+hyper-v+api&oq=msdn+hyper-v+api)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh850075(v=vs.85).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh850077(v=vs.85).aspx

http://blogs.technet.com/b/jamesone/archive/2008/01/24/hyper-v-api-information-on-msdn.aspx